# Failed to run Python script with Conda

Tags: python, anaconda, conda, menpo

I tried to install menpo like in [this tutorial](http://www.menpo.org/installation/windows/index.html). After that I installed menpofit, menpo3d and menpodetect:

> conda install -c menpo menpofit
>
> conda install -c menpo menpo3d
>
> conda install -c menpo menpodetect

Next I ran this python script from CMD(*python testPy.py*):

```
import menpo.io as mio
from menpo.visualize import visualize_images

images = list(mio.import_images('A:/img/*.png'))
visualize_images(images)
```

And got this output:
[image]
What am I doing wrong and how I can fix it?

Comment: Please put your error message into a code block, instead of posting an image. For people with a similar error it is very difficult to find your question as images are not indexed.

Comment: @cel is correct, that command is intended to be used from within an IPython notebook. If you really want to visualize an image outside of the notebook, you can visualize them one at a time by using `image.view()`

Comment: In the OP's defence, it's not very easy to copy text from the Windows cmd terminal.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems that `visualize_images` is meant to be used from `ipython-notebook`. Calling it in a regular `python` script does not seem to be intended by the authors.

See also the example in the [`Visualizing Objects`](http://menpo.readthedocs.org/en/latest/userguide/visualization.html#visualizing-a-list-of-2d-images) section of the docs:

```
%matplotlib inline
import menpo.io as mio
from menpo.visualize import visualize_images

# import_images is a generator, so we must exhaust the generator before
# we can visualize the list. This is because the widget allows you to
# jump arbitrarily around the list, which cannot be done with generators.
images = list(mio.import_images('./path/to/images/*.jpg'))
visualize_images(images)
```

Comment: Exactly correct @cel! The `visualize_images` command is in fact an IPython widget, and thus can only be used within an IPython notebook. At the moment, we haven't made a new release since the release of IPython 3, so we also currently require IPythn 2.x

Comment: @BeRecursive thanks! I have a small offtop question: Does the menpo use OpenCV for image processing for AAM/ASM?

Comment: @user2656632 No we don't use OpenCV at all, the majority of our code, except for key time consuming portions, is all written in pure Python. However, if you use the OpenCV Python interface, it should be trivial to fit images using OpenCV images and then convert them back again.

Comment: @BeRecursive I don't quite understand what you mean about "However, if you use the OpenCV Python interface, it should be trivial to fit images using OpenCV images and then convert them back again". Can you share the link or sample? Thanks!

Comment: I made the assumption that you were going to end up training/fitting images using MenpFit. I merely meant that you can convert the OpenCV images to Numpy arrays, which can then be wrapped as Menpo images. Once they are wrapped as Menpo images, you can use MenpoFit to find landmarks for them!